# UI slider: highlight available values into range

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've made UI range slider with min value=100 and max value=300. Realy available range is 200-300. How can I change color only of this range?

```
$("#slider-range_3").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 100,
    max: 300,
    values: [ 200, 300 ],
    slide: function(event,ui) {
        if(ui.values[0] < 200){
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

I want to hightlight passible range 200-300. How can i do that?

Picture: http://imglink.ru/pictures/01-07-14/dd1f2fb60080ad06388311fae7a7dfc0.jpg

Comment: You'll need to give more information than that

Comment: Ok, I created the example

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on the jQuery website

http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

**Update (hack):**

As I'm not sure if jQuery supports this out-of-the-box you could add your own div to do this:

```
$("#slider-range").append('<div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" style="left: 5%; width: 80%;background:#ff9900;"></div>');
```

You would need to get the percentages right though.

Comment: It's an example of simple range slider. I need to create hightlight only possible area (see picture)